# change category color base on id

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I would like to know how I can change the bg- color of each category name in a post loop I'm using Tailwind css but it's not working when I did it this way

```
@foreach( $posts as $post )

<span class="bg-{{$post->category->color()}}">{{$post->category->color}}</span>
@endforeach
```

In my category model I did this

```
public function color()
{
return isset($this->category) ? [
    0 => 'red',
    1 => 'green',
    2 => 'yellow',
    3 => 'blue',
    4 => 'purple'
  ][$this->category] : 'default';
}
```

Comment: Are these ‘...’ really the quotes you have in your source code? Only use `'` or `"` for source code.

Comment: the quote I have is this '...'

Comment: Okay good. So is `{{$post->category->color}}` outputting the color correctly but the background color isn't showing? "It's not working" is not a good description of the error you're having.

Comment: not outputting the color is the error I have

Comment: It does not print anything? Not even `default`? Well, you will eventually have to debug the variables' values: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you can fix it.

```
public function color()
{
    return isset($this->id) ? [
    0 => ‘red’,
    1 => ‘green’,
    2 => ‘yellow’,
    3 => ‘blue’,
    4 => ‘purple’
    ][$this->id] : ‘default’;
}
```